# Symbol cannot be resolved - Griffon (Intellij Idea 13)

Tags: intellij-idea

I have created a Griffon project in Intellij Idea 13. Griffon version is 1.5.0. In the whole project I can see many keywords which are underlined. When I move the cursor on underlined word following text appear as warning "Cannot resolve symbol". When I run the application it works fine. Please help me to resolve this error. See images below for details.

Comment: You seem to have forgotten the images...

Comment: Please download image using this link https://db.tt/sJtRmTII Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dependencies for Griffon projects in IntelliJ are not resolved correctly. This is a known limitation of the IntelliJ Griffon plugin. In order to have dependencies resolved correctly you must do the following:

1. open a terminal prompt
2. navigate the the project's directory
3. execute the following command: griffon integrate-with --idea
4. reopen the project in in IntelliJ

You must perform these steps every time you update dependencies in `griffon-app/conf/BuildConfig.groovy` or installing/uninstalling a plugin.

Answer (score 0):

The problem occurs by creating project in Intellij Idea. I performed following steps and my problem was solved.

1. Created project with following command ***griffon create-app*** DemoConsole
2. Executed the command ***griffon integrate-with --idea***
3. Opened the project in ***Intellij Idea***